# Calculating distance to polygon boundary with D3.js

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

I would like to create a map where you mouseover a geojson/topojson polygon, and any geojson/topojson polygons within a certain distance of that polygon are highlighted.

Is there a function or algorithm that can do this quickly? Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: You could iterate through all polygons and filter the ones that are too far away. If you want to compute the distance of the centroids, you can do that immediately through the D3 function that gets you that, otherwise it'll be trickier.

Comment: That sounds very slow, sadly.

Comment: Depends on the number of features. You could also use a quadtree or build an adjacency matrix/list at the beginning to make lookups faster.